# Converting an NSNumber to NSTimeInterval

Tags: objective-c, type-conversion, nsnumber, nstimeinterval

I've converted an NSTimeInterval to an NSNumber in order to store it in NSUserDefaults.  I used the numberWithDouble method like this:

```
NSNumber *savedTime = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:timeInterval];
```

I'm retrieving the information in another view, but I'm running into an issue.  The number doesn't seem to want to convert properly.  I know the number is carrying over, because I am able to view the number in this label, and it shows up properly:

```
timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [[[userDefaults objectForKey:groupTitleForReference] objectForKey:@"time"] doubleValue]];
```

but when I go to set the interval to the double value, it doesn't work.  I'm using this:

```
interval = [[[userDefaults objectForKey:groupTitleForReference] objectForKey:@"time"] doubleValue];
```

All variables are properly declared in the header.  Any idea why it's not working?

Thanks,

David

Comment: In what sense "it doesn't work", precisely?

Comment: What "doesn't work"? Can you show us what `interval` is after that line please?

Comment: can you show exactly what is your conversion problem? because "does not work" is not self explanatory

Comment: Does not work, as in it tries to read as 0.  I have checks to assess what number the value is.  If the value is 0, an alert goes off.  The alert goes off immediately.

Comment: Multimer[27707:c07] 6.000000  is how it shows up in my nslog, using %f as a format specifier

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, you use

```
[[[userDefaults objectForKey:groupTitleForReference] objectForKey:@"time"] doubleValue]
```

to get the `double` value.  You need to concentrate on what might be different.  Off the top of my head, look at:

- Is `interval` correctly declared as a `double` or `NSTimeInterval`?  Show us how and where you declare `interval`.
- When you display `interval` to check its value, are you displaying it correctly.  I've been known to do this by accident

  ```
  NSTimeInterval interval = ....
  NSLog(@"%@", interval);
  ```

  Show us the code you use to inspect the interval and its output.
- Has userDefaults changed?
- Has `groupTitleForReference` changed.

**EDIT**

Another thing to check

- If `interval` is a global make sure the declaration in the header is of the form

  ```
  extern NSTimeInterval interval;
  ```

  If you omit `extern`, you'll get a separate variable called `interval` in every file that includes the header.

Comment: Jeremy,

Thanks for the response.  To answer your questions:

1.  I have tried both directly assigning NSTimeInterval using the double value and declaring a double above it and assigning the NSTimeInterval from that double.  Neither way works. 

2.  When I NSLog interval, I use the %f format specifier, and it shows up correctly.  It also shows up correctly if I use the double specifier.  

3.  userDefaults has not changed.  No declarations were changed, and the only difference is I'm passing an NSNumber instead of the NSTimeInterval.

Comment: 4.  groupTitle has not changed.  It's dynamic depending on which option the user selects in the table from the previous view.  

The code runs properly if I pass an nstimeinterval directly from a singleton I had set up, but it doesn't work if I pass through just a float or double and try to convert it to an nstimeinterval.

I hope that makes sense.  I'm still learning, only a few months in my objective c courses

Comment: If you NSLog it with %f and it's correct, then there's nothing wrong.  Why do you think you have a problem?

Comment: There is a problem, because my code is not registering that there is a value to interval.  

This code is being hit immediately, when it should not:

    if (interval == 0 || interval < 0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Timer is done" message:@"Time's up" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alertView show];
    }

Again, this was all functioning properly a few minutes ago when I passed an nstimeinterval directly, but not when I'm converting from nsnumber to nstimeinterval.  Also, I believe I answerd everything

Comment: No, you haven't answered everything.  You are telling me that when you NSLog interval, it is correct, but then in that if test, it is not correct.  There is *no* way for this to happen unless you are not telling us everything.  Where is `interval` declared?

Comment: I just saw your edit, I didn't see you had asked that question or I would have answered it.

Comment: interval isn't being accessed from any other view controllers.  I'm not setting it from another file.  I'm setting it from inside that view controller, using data from NSUserDefaults.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: I logged interval in another function inside of the same viewcontroller and it resets to 0.  I'm setting it in viewDidLoad, and when I log it there, it shows up correctly.  Any other function has it showing as 0.  I'm confused as to why, with no other edits to my code other than the location of the stored data for the nstimeinterval, it would be reseting back to 0 outside of that function...

Comment: Nevermind.  I'm going to avoid extended discussions.  Thanks for the help, Jeremy.  I apologize that I'm not answering your questions correctly.  I'll take my downvote with dignity.